# Does the post Apollo 13 roast mixtape still exist?

Tags: nasa, apollo-program, history, apollo-13

> The debriefing party at the Hofbraugarten was merciless, beginning
> with a parody of the mission. The tape prepared by the Apollo 13
> backup crew and the CapComs was not for the thin-skinned. The parody
> began and ended with the "immortal words" Liebergot and I exchanged
> early in the crisis.
>
> Kranz: "I don't understand that, Sy."
>
> Liebergot: "I think we may have had an instrumentation problem,
> Flight."
>
> The clips of the voice tapes from the mission and the press
> conferences were interwoven with a Spike Jones record, gospel music,
> and various sound effects. No one was spared. As the tape continued,
> the crews and controllers roared and poured more beer. The tape took a
> shot at every flight director and crew member, as well as Slayton,
> Kraft, and even President Nixon. By the time the evening was over the
> words "I don't understand that, Sy" were forever embedded in memory.

Failure Is Not an Option by Gene Kranz [page 338](https://books.google.com/books?id=slQZ3JOUSKQC&pg=PA338&lpg=PA338)

Does a recording of this tape still exist? And if it does, is it available online anywhere?

Comment: Wow, the Hofbraugarten has been gone since before I started working at JSC. I would love if somebody comes up with the tape.

Comment: Hofbräugarten is the correct spelling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This reel-to-reel tape was digitized and then published on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Apollo13Parody/Apollo13Parody.mp3) on 2012 Feb 22,
by [John Stoll](https://www.mixonline.com/recording/nasa-audio-finds-home-web-mission-archive-sounds-us-space-flight-372008), lead audio engineer at Johnson Space Center.  NASA has placed it in the public domain.  Enjoy!

Comment: Wow! Nice job finding that.

Comment: I'd seen this question in the queue for ages, but only today thought to look in the Archive.  John's put a ton of audio and video (with transcriptions) there over the years, which should be great for other answers.

Comment: Thank you for that link; the Internet Archive continues to be a world treasure. The article is informative but a bit weird "there are no manned space flights planned for the near future" lol but hey, I miss the shuttle too.

Comment: :-) Thank you, in turn, for the bounty surprise!