# How often in NASA history was "Houston, we have a problem" or deviations actually said?

Tags: history, communication, failure

The phrase "Houston, we've had a problem" was said by Jim Lovell after the oxygen tank blew up during Apollo 13, and in the movie Tom Hanks playing Jim Lovell said "Houston, we have a problem". However, given the many incidents in NASA spaceflights, isn't it likely that such phrases were said more often by American crews?

Other than during Apollo 13, "Houston, we have a problem" or similar could have been said for example by the following crews:

- Gus Grissom after the Liberty Bell's splashdown (in this case "I have a problem")
- Gemini 6A during a failed launch attempt
- Gemini 8 after it started to spin
- Apollo 1 during the fatal launch rehearsal test
- Apollo 11 when Buzz Aldrin accidentally damaged a circuit braker for lunar launch
- Apollo 12 after being struck by lightning during ascent
- the Apollo-Soyuz Apollo crew during landing
- STS-51-F during their abort to orbit
- STS-51 during a satellite release device detonation
- STS-83 when a fuel cell failed
- STS-107 during the fatal reentry

Comment: Never again seriously, often as a joke. No way to prove it though. Frankly people at JSC are kind of sick of the phrase due to its overuse in the media.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for both the words "problem" and "Houston" being used when they first contacted mission control about a problem? Seems unlikely, but probably can't be ruled out without locating comms for each incident. For Apollo 12 it was: "_Okay, we just lost the platform, gang. I don't know what happened here; we had everything in the world drop out."_

Comment: I worked as an ISS flight controller for three years, never once did I hear any variation of "Houston, we have a problem" on the loops. And I was on console for the MS-10 launch abort, 
the August 2018 atmospheric leak, and many, many more payload anomalies. The crew tends to be much more succinct and actually state what's wrong instead of wasting time with a nondescript "problem."

Comment: @StevePemberton Not necessarily Houston, but they call on Houston anyway unless the "we have a problem" is being said between crew members only (as Jack Swigert did when the tank exploded). In that case, they'd have to be on *vox* (that's what it's called in the movie) for mission control to hear them.

Comment: @Doresoom But isn't there some analog to the "Mayday" in airplanes? Like, saying if there's something wrong in the first place.

Comment: @OldManJohn Everyone listens intently whenever loop traffic on space to ground keys up, no need for the crew to use a special code word for immediate attention. If there's something wrong in telemetry that's an absolute emergency, flight controllers use "break, break" at the start of their message to get everyone to stop talking on the loop and listen. I only used that once in my career when crew was about to demate a vacuum hose QD that didn't have the outboard vent valve closed.

Comment: Even in sims when we were throwing the book at them they never said it except as an ironic joke.

Comment: @OldManJohn In air traffic control, the main purpose of a distress call like mayday (emergency) or panpan (urgent but not life threatening) is to clear the frequency. It means "everybody shut up, I need to talk without interference", because there are normally dozens of aircraft doing stuff at any given time and a constant stream of radio calls sharing the same frequency. In space, we generally only have one mission on a given frequency, so there's not really anyone else around that needs to be silenced.

Comment: sort of related: [the Apollo 13 parody tape](https://archive.org/details/Apollo13Parody/Apollo13Parody.mp3) and the [question here that should suffice as an explanation for why there is such a thing](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/60107/does-the-post-apollo-13-roast-mixtape-still-exist)

Comment: @DarthPseudonym as Doresoom mentioned there is a need to shut up all the controllers talking on the loops.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Right, but what they're talking about is an extreme condition where seconds matter. I'm just expanding on that comment to explain how busy and chaotic an ATC channel is by comparison.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Exactly, talking over S/G is a flight controller cardinal sin! Although by the time I left NASA in 2019 it had sometimes become necessary since on occasion we had traffic on all 4 S/G loops simultaneously. Those shifts were a real headache, and were only manageable by staffing in a secondary for each of the the main POIC console positions.

Comment: @Doresoom listening to the loops was definitely a learned skill! Shuttle had less loops up to the ship, but as a Systems instructor I had to monitor three teams of flight controllers, the flight loop, the loop to the instructor in the simulator building, and the Air-to-Grounds. My first day of on-the-job-training in the MCC it was just a mass of noise.